# Is it possible to change from bits to bytes in the Windows 8 Task Manager?

Tags: windows-8

I feel much more familiar with bytes than bits, and the Task Manager defaults to Mbps and Kbps:

[image]

I've poked around, but haven't seen any option to change it. Is it possible to change it?

Comment: bps is the standard and i doubt there would be any official setting allowing the b->B conversion. I'm not sure of any 3rd party apps though

Comment: Possibilities are endless, there is a concept of code injection that can manipulate or at least show equivalent speed in bytes in almost any running executable. Code injection can atleast add new feature like buttons and menus with respective actions so if not manipulate displayed values it can additionally show equivalent speed in bytes. But it's too much of an effort and won't be a standard practice to quote speed in bytes. If you really want some c++ developer with might able to help.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot change the value in Task manager as eluded to by Alexy Ivanov, but you can view B/sec in resource monitor by clicking the link at the bottom of TM, then  drop down the Network tab. Much more information in Resource Monitor should you need it.

.
[image]

.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it's possible.

Using bits is standard in measuring network speeds.
Ethernet cards usually support 10 Mbps, 100 Mbps, 1 Gbps speed.

These graphs include the service data transferred, not only the data itself. Because of reception errors, especially in Wi-Fi networks, the useful data transfer rate may be lower than the connection speed.